# Get values from a form in jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

I have want to get values from my form in `jquery`

**Here is my html code:**

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-condensed">
    <tbody><tr id="properties_view">
        <td><h4>Location</h4></td>
        <td><h4>Substage</h4></td>
        <td><h4>Crypted</h4></td>
        <td><h4>Key</h4></td>
        <td><h4>Value</h4></td>
        <td><h4>Comments</h4></td>
        <td><h4>Delete</h4></td>
    </tr>
<tr><td class="value">ANY</td><td class="value">MAIN </td><td class="value">false</td><td class="value">unitesbudg_roic_assetcenter.V01.aaf.filename</td><td class="value">unitesbudg_roic_assetcenter.txt</td><td class="value">undefined</td><td><a href="#" class="delete_line" id="unitesbudg_roic_assetcenter.V01.aaf.filename"><img src="img/delete.png"></a></td></tr>

<tr><td class="value">ANY</td><td class="value">MAIN </td><td class="value">false</td><td class="value">personnes_roic_assetcenter.V01.aaf.filename</td><td class="value">personnes_roic_assetcenter.txt</td><td class="value">undefined</td><td><a href="#" class="delete_line" id="personnes_roic_assetcenter.V01.aaf.filename"><img src="img/delete.png"></a></td></tr>

<tr><td class="value">ANY</td><td class="value">MAIN </td><td class="value">false</td><td class="value">common.aaf.folder</td><td class="value">ROI/out/</td><td class="value">undefined</td><td><a href="#" class="delete_line" id="common.aaf.folder"><img src="img/delete.png"></a></td></tr>

</tbody></table>
```

I tried this js but it doesnt work

Here is my `js` code. When I click the button `<a href="#" class="commit_properties" id=""><button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Commit</button></a>` I try to debug in the Chrome Console.

```
$("#page_body").on('click', 'a.commit_properties', function(e) { 
    var debug;
    debug = $(this).$('table').text();
    console.debug(debug); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you don't need to wrap your button in an anchor tag. In fact I don't see any reason why you'd want to. To loop through the values in your table, use JQuery's `each` function:

```
$("#page_body").on('click', 'button', function (e) {
   $('.value').each(function(i,e){
        console.log($(e).text());       
    });
});
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78pp3/).